# How do I run an executable JAR file using Ansible?

Tags: java, jar, ansible, executable-jar

I am trying to use Ansible to run a JAR file (to install a software) any idea how I can do this?

So far I've done this which does nothing:

```
- name: installJar
  win_command: "java -jar C:/projects/core/installer.jar"
```

After doing this, I get no errors or anything, it just becomes stuck and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hi, try to add -vv to increase verbosity and second tip what's the output of `java -version`

Comment: I added -vv and it doesn't show anything as it continues to run without stopping. Java -version does not have an output, although, it runs fine and shows the text in yellow which signifies that a change has been made.

Comment: give full java path as win_command `will not be processed through the shell` so maybe you don't have java PATH env variable set.